# Interpreting fsck_hfs result

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, fsck-hfs

While trying to understand why my Mac stopped performing so well on Spotlight.. I tried a suggestion that had me check my HD's status on Disk Utility. I can't press the `Unmount` button even after using `First-Aid`, weird. So this led me to searching this [link](https://www.cnet.com/uk/how-to/how-to-check-for-and-fix-os-x-boot-drive-errors/) - an old one but informative - and tried the commands there.

For the two other commands I got the expected result. Using `sudo fsck_hfs -f /dev/disk0s2` or `-fy`, however.. (`-y` for `Always attempt to repair any damage that is found` ) while this is expected:

[image]

I got the following result. Same when typed -f in place of -fy.

[image]

This seemed troublesome. But shame I don't have a clue what is the issue nor how to deal with it. Could anyone share some insight please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to check the file system on disk0s2 with the wrong tool. `fsck_hfs` targets HFS file systems. Your main drive is formatted to APFS though.

The output of `sudo fsck_hfs -fy /dev/disk0s2` in your screenshot shows the first block of the/an APFS container. This is indicated by the NXSB magic string in the third line.

The proper tool to check APFS containers or volumes is `fsck_apfs`!

Check `man fsck_apfs` for further details.

---

Since `diskutil verifyDisk|verifyVolume|repairDisk|repairVolume [device]` also calls `fsck_apfs` or another appropriate `fsck_*` tool with the **proper** flags I'd prefer this command instead:

```
diskutil list # to get the device identifiers
diskutil verifyDisk disk0
diskutil verifyVolume disk0s2
diskutil verifyVolume disk1s1
```

If required, repair the container/volume with:

```
diskutil repairDisk disk0s
diskutil repairVolume disk0s2
diskutil repairVolume disk1s1
```

Comment: Commenting on an old answer here, but I get a fairly similar result when running `fsck_hfs` on an external 1.5TB HDD which won’t mount, and which Disk Utility says it can’t repair. I’m fairly sure my disk is _not_ APFS (at least according to `diskutil list`). I get three output blocks, all of which are blank (no letters, just dots); the relevant section of `diskutil list` and the total output of `sudo /sbin/fsck_hfs -fy /dev/disk2s2` can be seen [in this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Jjk92CyN). Does that output make any sense? And is it normal that fsck takes _hours_ to run?